# iterate through XML file using JQUERY / AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I have a code like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

    var x, i ,xmlDoc;
    var txt = "";
    var text = "";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET" ,
        url: "data.xml" ,
        dataType: "xml" ,
        success: function(xml) {

            //  xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);

            $(xml).find('object').each(function(){
                console.log($(this).text());
                console.log($(this).nodeName);
            });
        }
    });


    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This spits out the values of the fields, however how do I get the names of the XML nodes as well? So in a file like:

```
   <root>
<item>hello</item>
</root>
```

I only get "hello"

I need something like "item" and "hello"

is it possible, if so, how? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the sample XML, I have shown this sample. You can replace them with the dynamic XML.

```js
var x, i ,xmlDoc;
var txt = "";
var text = "";
// Replace with your dynamic xml
var text = "<root>"+
"<item>hello</item>"+
"</root>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

// documentElement always represents the root node
x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
  console.log("Node :",x[i].nodeName);
  console.log("Value :",x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  txt += x[i].nodeName + ": " + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("xmlData").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<div id="xmlData"></div>
```

Source : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_parsertest3

Comment: Thanks, I found that one yesterday, I failed to load the XML file to the text variable, but I will make it working somehow, I am quite sure ;) Have a good day!

Comment: i guess you didn't want to define the ''text" variable two times (var) only at first time(?) Seems useful code otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an `object` tag which is not present in the xml response. (Also since you are using the `datatype: 'xml'` JQuery will return an XMLElement). Instead look for the `item` tags and then you can access the `nodeName` & `textContent` properties.

https://jsfiddle.net/zms0qwa1/

Comment: Thank you, it is getting me somewhere, however I posted a wrong sample XML file. Actually, my XML file is <objects><object>... many other nodes like <name><quantity> ... </object></objects> and I need to iterate them dynamically. Your suggestions is manually entering each node name? Is it possible to iterate all nodes and get their names and values dynamically. The nodes in the XML file might be changing each time, but always in objects/object. Thanks again, appreciated!